Is there a standard way for unique file content per user in Javascript
I am running a server in which users get a javascript file when they sign up. They can use this on their website, and I can track it.
So people register through my expressjs project, but to change the JS file they will receive, i use this code.
    if (checkExists[0]['COUNT(1)'] == 1n) {
        const options = {
            files: 'src/sdk.js',
            from: 'var Hh="-4534939823",',
            to: `var Hh="${chatId}",`,
          }
        fs.copyFile('theFile.js', 'src/sdk.js', (err) => { //copy file to
            if (err) throw err;
          });

        try { //replace chatID
            const result = await replaceInFile(options)
            console.log(result)
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
        child_process.execSync(`zip -r src.zip src`);
  
        a.finally(() => {
            child_process.exec('rm src/sdk.js; rm src.zip')
        })
    }

So i create a duplicate of the original -> edit lines -> zip the file -> send it back
I have a big feeling that this will fail over time. Is there a standard way / package in Node for such tasks?
it works, but is it optimal?

Just a comment here that if (err) throw err; where you have it is worthless error handling.  And, your fs.copyFile() statement is asynchronous, but you're not coding to use the asynchronous result.  And, there's a race condition since multiple user's requests could be attempting to both use the sdk.js that you're modifying.  You should use temp files that are unique for every request and then clean them up when done with  them.  There are lots of problems with this code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't overwrite the same file each time. Copy to a new, temporary file.
